# Passing reference to constructor, default argument

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qcustomplot

I'm creating an own Qt C+ class that is supposed to take a reference to a QCustomPlot from the ui-> as input argument to the constructor.

It should look like this:

```
myPlots::myPlots(QObject *parent, QCustomPlot& _plot ) :
    QObject(parent), plot(_plot)
{


}
```

I dont want to create the plot area programmatically as it's neater do to it in the UI edit. And don't wish to use a pointer as argument as references are safer and more syntax clean as I understand. However I get the following error:

**"error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of 'myPlots::myPlots(QObject*, QCustomPlot&)'
     explicit myPlots(QObject *parent=0, QCustomPlot& _plot);"**

I tried  =0 and =null as default argument but only got errors. What is happening here?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to try to set a reference to 0 or Null. Why don't you just call it the right way? Can you show the declaration in the header file, please? Would it be possible to also show how you use this constructor?

Comment: Can you show the class declaration? Especially how you declare the `plot` member?

Answer (score 4):

The error in your question is because arguments with default values must be *after* arguments without default values, those are the rules of C++.

---

As for having the `_plot` argument having a default value, it kind of depends on how the `plot` member variable is declared. If it's not a reference, you can make the `_plot` argument a reference to a constant instead and have a default-constructed `QCustomPlot` object as default value:

```
myPlots(QObject *parent = nullptr, const QCustomPlot& _plot = QCustomPlot(parent));
```

However, this only works if the `plot` member is ***not*** a reference. If it *is* a reference, then you should probably have two constructors: One taking a `QCustomPlot` reference, and one without:

```
myPlots(QObject *parent = nullptr);
myPlots(QCustomPlot& plot_, QObject *parent = nullptr);
```

The first constructor needs to create a `QCustomPlot` instance that is never destroyed during the lifetime of the `myPlots` instance being constructed, and use that for the reference.

Comment: The OP seems to have the zero parent for the first argument, but not the second as per compiler output. He also tried it for the second argument, so I am not sure this really is the issue. If the trial is truth, then not.

Comment: That is the issue, default arguments must be AFTER the ones without defaults.

Comment: @dornhege: not really, the OP tried default argument for the second, too.

Comment: Update: the temporary will get destroyed and the reference will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Note that I specifically say that the `plot` member can't be a reference if using the reference-to-constant solution.

Comment: Well, you updated your answer after my comments. Either way, IMHO, reference here is a strange concept if you ask me. It might be just me that I have almost never seen this in Qt software the last couple of years except mistakes, and none of the Qt API works like that either in my experience. Your suggestion makes it work, true, but I would not personally use it, still. Perhaps, I am too stuck with the 99% convention out there, including QCustomPlot usages.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: nullptr will not compile without C++11 support, whereas Qt does. Also, while you are at C++11, you could consider explicit for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use default arguments (for functions or templates), there's no way to indicate a skipped argument, you can only leave some off at the end.
Therefore, C++ forces you to provide defaults for any argument following one having such.
If there's no good default for the second but for the first, use multiple constructors or change the arguments ordering.

If you really want to give a default for a l-value reference argument (non-const and non-move), use a global static object.
For other references / non-references, constructing an object just there is ok.

Do not try to force C++ to accept a non-object using cute tricks, if you do you really deserve the **Undefined Behavior** you get.

Example for static object:

```
struct myPlots {
    explicit myPlots(QObject *parent = 0, QCustomPlot& _plot = standard_plot);
    static QCustomPlot standard_plot;
}
```

Example for reordering:

```
struct myPlots {
    explicit myPlots(QCustomPlot& _plot, QObject *parent = 0);
}
```

Example for overloads:

```
struct myPlots {
    myPlots(QObject *parent, QCustomPlot& _plot);
    explicit myPlots(QCustomPlot& _plot);
}
```

Comment: It is not a good idea in Qt software not to initialize the parent to zero by default. Currently, I cannot mention any use case where that happens even in Qt. Also, when you use default values, you may wish to consider explicit, particularly with C++11 on.

Comment: 0 is not a good idea with C++11 for null pointer, btw. It is better to use nullptr in that case.

Comment: @LaszloPapp `0` is a wonderful idea, wherever there can be no ambiguity, like when you define and use a pointer in the same statement. That fits here.

Comment: So, you are claiming the C++ committee needlessly introduced nullptr to replace 0? What if your code is updated? I do not see any compelling reason not to use the right in the first place. Also, why do you think Qt has migrated away from `0`?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Using `NULL` is for making your intentions clear to the reader but unfortunately does not neccessarily do the same for the compiler. `nullptr` does the same for both, though they should have changed `NULL` in a backward-compatible way instead imho. Still, if there cannot be any ambiguity, getting more verbose is just noise.

Comment: I am not sure what backward compatibility you are speaking about. They kept backward compatibility in this regard. Also, at no point did I mention `NULL` as even Bjarne declares that broken. ^^

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I mentioned `NULL` for completeness, you wanting to answer to the main point too?

Comment: Yep, I would personally avoid the non-const reference, but perhaps even the reference concept myself, even if QCP is not COW, but it might just be strong convention.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

> In a given function declaration, each parameter subsequent to a
>   parameter with a default argument shall have a default argument
>   supplied in this or a previous declaration or shall be a function
>   parameter pack.

and

> A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or
>   function. [ Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a
>   well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference
>   would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a
>   null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to set a reference to zero or NULL directly or indirectly. To be fair, setting it directly will probably not even work because it will fail to compile, and the rest will have undefined behavior.

However, the compiler is trying to help you how to use the constructor:

> myPlots::myPlots(QObject *parent, QCustomPlot& _plot ) :
>       QObject(parent), plot(_plot)

In constructors setting parents, you usually leave the parent as the last argument with default null pointer value, or you get an overloaded version with the parent only. Although that is not the main issue in here.

The issue is that you are trying to use a reference without a valid object. You need to initialize references to "valid" objects. You could initialize it to null pointer through a proxy object, this the quote. You could set a const reference to a temporary object, but that would have undefined behavior as the temporary get destructed abruptly.

I would personaly suggest to reconsider your design and use pointer or value semantics. References are good in general, but I do not see the gain of it in this particular case.

So, I would personally write something like this:

#### header file

```
explicit myPlots(QCustomPlot _plot, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
```

or

```
explicit myPlots(QCustomPlot *_plot = 0, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
```

Before you start asking about `Q_NULLPTR` in a comment, it is not magical. It is a hidden gem, but it is possible to use it freely as the maintainer said it will not break. It simply falls back to `0` without C++11 or later support, otherwise it is defined to `nullptr`, so your software will work with both.